# Dismiss keyboard when touching outside of UITextField in iwatch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I know that I need to tell my UITextField to resign first responder when I want to dismiss the keyboard, but I'm not sure how to know when the user has pressed the `out side of view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling touch view delegate method provided as below.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Let me know in case of any concern.

Answer (score 1):

It will Hide Keyboard.
i hope it will work for you.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapper;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hop it helps..

you can simply add UITapGestureRecognizer to your self.view

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(taped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)taped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    //resign first responder
}
```

Comment: What happen if i tap on other UI object or control?

Answer (score 0):

You can try touchesEnded method

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [yourTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```